# React class context set sometimes but not all

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-bootstrap

I'm very new to all of this (about three days in), so forgive my ignorance.

I'm using a combination of React, React-Router, and React-Bootstrap.  Like [this guy](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/issues/83), I want to combine React-Router's `<Link />` and React-Bootstrap's `<NavItem />`'s functionality so that the `.active` class is applied to the `<li>` element rather (or as well as) the `<a>` element.

What's really frustrating is I had this working, and then it stopped when I made, what seemed to me, some unrelated changes (that I *believe* I've undone, since).

Here's my code:

#### listlink.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Router from 'react-router';
import classNames from 'classnames';

let Link = Router.Link;

let ListLink = React.createClass({
    contextTypes: {
        router: React.PropTypes.func
    },

    /* copied from React-Bootstrap's NavItem.js */
    propTypes: {
        onSelect: React.PropTypes.func,
        active: React.PropTypes.bool,
        disabled: React.PropTypes.bool,
        href: React.PropTypes.string,
        title: React.PropTypes.node,
        eventKey: React.PropTypes.any,
        target: React.PropTypes.string
    },

    render: function () {
        /* error happens here */
        let isActive = this.context.router.isActive(this.props.to);

        /* copied from React-Bootstrap's NavItem.js */
        let {
            disabled,
            active,
            href,
            title,
            target,
            children,
            ...props } = this.props;

        let classes = {
            'active': isActive,
            'disabled': disabled
        };

        return (
            <li { ...props } className={ classNames(props.classNames, classes) }>
                <Link to={ this.props.to }>{ this.props.children }</Link>
            </li>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = ListLink;
```

#### app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Router from 'react-router';
import classNames from 'classnames';
import ListLink from '../components/listlink';
import BS from 'react-bootstrap';

/* ... */

let DefaultRoute = Router.DefaultRoute;
let Route = Router.Route;
let RouteHandler = Router.RouteHandler;

let Nav = BS.Nav;
let Navbar = BS.Navbar;

let App = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div>
                <Navbar brand={this.props.toonName} fixedTop>
                    <Nav bsStyle='tabs'>
                        <ListLink to="toon">Character</ListLink>
                        <ListLink to="spell-book">Spell Book</ListLink>
                        <ListLink to="on-your-turn">On Your Turn</ListLink>
                        <ListLink to="battle" disabled={true}>Battle</ListLink>
                    </Nav>
                </Navbar>
                <RouteHandler />
            </div>
        );
    }
});

let routes = (
    <Route name="app" path="/" handler={App} toonName="Ivellios">
        <Route name="toon" handler={Toon} />
        <Route name="spell-book" handler={SpellBook} />
        <Route name="on-your-turn" handler={OnYourTurn} />
        <Route name="battle" handler={Battle} />
        <DefaultRoute handler={Toon} />
    </Route>
);

Router.run(routes, function (Handler) {
    React.render(<Handler toonName="Ivellios" />, document.body);
});

module.exports = App;
```

When I set a breakpoint at `let isActive =...` in `listlink.js`, it breaks 5 times, one time for each `<ListLink>` and then a fifth time where `this.props.to` is `toon` again.  It's this fifth time where `this.context.router` is `undefined`, and referencing `.isActive` throws an error.

I thought maybe it was because of the `<DefaultRoute />` declaration, but that doesn't seem to be the case (commenting the line out doesn't make a difference).  Regardless of which `/#/[page]` is in the URL, it's always `toon` on the fifth iteration, and it always fails with the same error.

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isActive' of undefined`

I don't know how to debug this any further.  Ideas?

Comment: Could your `App` component be used somewhere else? You're exporting it from `app.js`, another file might be importing it and trying to render it.

Comment: Good thought, but it doesn't seem to be the case.  (I did a quick find string on the whole project directory.)

Comment: react-bootstrap might be tinkering with the elements you pass as children to `Navbar` or `Nav`, try moving your `<ListLink>` elements up two levels and see if you still get an error.

Comment: Also, are you creating `<ListLink>` elements anywhere else?

Comment: I get the same error if I move the links, and I'm not using them anywhere else.  If I remove the links entirely, I get a new error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRouteAtDepth' of undefined` in ReactRouter.js

Comment: Your `App` component is rendered somewhere without `router` being set in the `context`. I don't see it happening anywhere in the code you've shown.

Comment: Found it.  main.cs (my entry point) was rendering it, and app.cs itself was also rendering it.  Thanks!